# Recording goes from loud to quiet with constant sound

Tags: microphone, audio-recording, software, audacity, laptop

When I record with audacity (I haven't tried other programs yet) I have loud parts and very soft parts in the recording. Some parts are just missing (flat line). The microphone didn't move and neither did the object creating the sound. The microphone is the built-in one in the Toshiba Satellite S50t-B008/0H, Windows 8.

How do I make sure the microphone records consistently?

Comment: I haven't used those built-in microphones a lot but I suspect that is your problem. There's probably something in the driver or elsewhere that automatically adjusts the input level for that microphone and even mutes it if the level falls below a certain value. There's a chance that muting your speakers will help the microphone since sometimes built-in mics adjust based on the speaker output.

Comment: Can you link to a sample file?  It would be useful to know how quick the cut-outs are and what a normalized file looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Built-in mics typically have a massive amount of compression and also variable makeup gain and/or reduction assigned to it at the OS level prior to its input ever making into your DAW software. Likewise, depending on your system's setup, it might also have a gate on it, too, which could explain a lack of something recorded. The signal at that time of your recording might never have reached the threshold to open the gate. The gate, if present, might also be something that was enabled in Audacity, so look there, too.

Maybe look into getting a more decent USB mic (there are a lot of affordable models around, e.g. by [Blue](http://www.bluemic.com/snowball/) or [Samson](http://www.samsontech.com/samson/products/microphones/usb-microphones/meteormic/) or [Behringer](http://www.behringer.com/en/Products/C-1U.aspx) etc.), and avoid the internal mic completely.